# How to pass $_POST from one controller to another in Kohana

Tags: kohana-3

I have a template based project in Kohana. A search form is rendered as a part of common sections of template. The searching mechanism is handled by controller called calendar. I want to call controller calendar in user controller, which I could achieve by

```
$this->request->redirect('calendar');
```

But, in calendar, $_POST is empty. How can I access $_POST which was set by submitting the search form in user controller?

Answer (score 2):

`Request::redirect()` terminates the execution and responds with a 302 Location redirect header. Of course, you can't access the previous POST on the new page.

HMVC subrequesting can be used for cases like this:

```
$response = Request::factory('calendar')
    ->method(Request::POST)
    ->post($this->request->post())
    ->execute();
```

Comment: This gives error "call to undefined method 'method'". My Kohana version is 3.0. :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution to your problem, if you are unable to use HMVC subrequesting, is to store the $_POST variables you need into the session:

```
$my_var1 = $this->request->post('my_var1');
$my_var2 = $this->request->post('my_var2');

$session = Session::instance();

$session->set('my_var1', $my_var1);
$session->set('my_var2', $my_var2);

$this->request->redirect('calendar');
```

Then, in your calendar controller/action you can access said variables from the session:

```
$session = Session::instance();
$my_var1 = $session->get('my_var1');
$my_var2 = $session->get('my_var2');
```